# CodeModel: manually insert import statement

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

How do I manually insert an import statement using [CodeModel](http://codemodel.java.net/)?

I'd like to use [Arrays.toString(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) in a direct statement.

Context: I'm generating a toString() method in the generated code just like Eclipse does. The Arrays class is used to avoid printing references to the arrays I have declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to reference the class:

```
JClass arrays = codeModel.ref(Arrays.class);
```

Comment: Is that really everything you need to do? That doesn't work for me.

Comment: It works for me, but maybe your problem is that you don't use it after you get a reference to it? Did you call a method on the reference? I use it for:
arrays.staticInvoke("toString").arg(JExpr._this().ref(fieldName))

Comment: I use it in a textual method name `definedClass.staticInvoke("<Aspect>builder")`. I haven't found another way to parametrize a generic call to a method. I see that I need to use the referenced class, but invoking method as a string doesn't actually use it, whether I `.ref` the `Aspect.class` before the invocation or not. For now to get it imported I create an extra field with that type ("actually use the JClass"), but that is hell of a dirty hack.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to referance the class by its full package declarationinside the direct statement.

This is a bite of code I am currently writing, notice the full package declaration.
I also write some helpers or enum types to rapidly generate the full path of a certain class as String.

```
save.addClickListener(event -> {
        if (binder.writeBeanIfValid(pojo())) {
            infoLabel.setText("Saved bean values: " + pojo());
        } else {
            com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BinderValidationStatus<POJO> validate = binder.validate();
            String errorText = validate.getFieldValidationStatuses()
                    .stream().filter(com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BindingValidationStatus::isError)
                    .map(com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.BindingValidationStatus::getMessage)
                    .map(java.util.Optional::get).distinct()
                    .collect(java.util.streamCollectors.joining(", "));
            infoLabel.setText("There are errors: " + errorText);
        }
    });
```